# how to set HDF5_DIR to the hdf5 installation directory on mac

Tags: hdf5

CMake Error at cmake/thirdparty/SetupGeosxThirdParty.cmake:131 (message):
GEOSX requires hdf5, set HDF5_DIR to the hdf5 installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `cmake` file you are using is named `GEOSX/host-configs/ubuntu-gcc.cmake`, add this at the top (replace `<my_base_dir>` with whatever the GeosX base directory)

```
# file: ubuntu-gcc.cmake

set(BASE_DIR "<my_base_dir>" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)

# if building TPLs from the tplMirror repository, set GEOSX_TPL_DIR variable to point to the TPL installation path...
set(GEOSX_TPL_DIR "${BASE_DIR}/thirdPartyLibs/install-ubuntu-gcc-release" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
# ... , and
include("${BASE_DIR}/GEOSX/host-configs/tpls.cmake")
```

Then all third party libraries will be found.
I passed this hurdle, although I could not finalize compilation.